# Robustness of Gaussian Copula

Tags: normal-distribution, robust, copula

I am looking for studies regarding the robustness of a multivariate Gaussian copula. Specifically I am wondering whether estimates of the dependence parameter in a multivariate Gaussian Copula (Sigma) are robust to violations of the underlying assumptions. Many approaches that rely on normal distribution assumptions tend to be robust when those assumptions are violated. I am wondering whether the same extends to the Gaussian copula.

Let me give you some more details on the problem I am struggling with: I am using the approach proposed by Hoff 2007 to estimate the dependence structure between a set of demographic variables. The problem is that the sample I am using is biased in the sense that some demographic groups are over- and others under-represented (e.g., too many old people). I am wondering to which extent my estimate of the dependence structure is robust to mild forms of bias.

Thanks very much for your help in advance.

Michael

Hoff, Peter D. (2007), "Extending the Rank Likelihood for Semiparametric Copula Estimation," The annals of applied statistics, 1 (1), 265 - 83